# Subfigures with different angles rotated

Tags: graphics, rotating, subfig

Here is my latex code,

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering \subfigure[A Circle]{\label{fig:circle}%
\includegraphics[height=0.7in,clip]{rectangle}}
\hspace{0.1in}
\subfigure[A Rectangle]{\label{fig:rectangle}%
\includegraphics[height=1in,clip, angle=90]{rectangle}}
\hspace{0.1in}
\subfigure[A Rectangle]{\label{fig:rectangle}%
\includegraphics[height=0.7in,clip, angle=-19]{rectangle}}
\caption{(a) A Circle, (b) A Rectangle}
\label{fig:subfigex}
\end{figure}
```

The first pic is my following output. However, I don't know how to make it like the seconde one. Can you help me?

p\s: Dont care about the caption, I'm just testing

[image: So, the output is:]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: First, the subfigure package is obsolete.  One can use \subfloat from the subfig or subcaption (preferred) packages.  Second, you can use \raisebox to adjust the relative heights (baselines) of the subfigures.